# Ant automation of InstallAnywhere installers - console mode

Tags: ant, installation, 7zip

My problem is to create an ant target for automating our installer running in console mode.

The installer is created using InstallAnywhere 2008, which UniversalExtractor recognizes as a 7-zip archive.  Once I have the archive unpacked, it appears that the  task can use an input file to drive the console (at the very least, it appears that emitting a quit shuts everything down correctly, and output is captured).

So it looks to me as though I have all of the pieces I need for proving out this idea except a clean way to perform-self-extraction-then-stop.  Searching for a command-line argument to stop the auto execution has not produced a likely candidate, and the only suitable ant task I've found ( http://www.pharmasoft.be/7z/ ) isn't so clearly documented that I have a lot of confidence in it.

The completed completed is expected to work in Windows, Linux, and a small handful of other Unix environments.

What's the best practice to use here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you control the installer creation, can you run the self-extraction step on your machine, package the results before the installer is launched in a ZIP file, etc. and use that instead of the single file executable? Not very elegant but it may work.

Also, I am a bit hesitant to blatantly promote my project :)  but since it has been a while since you asked the question and nobody has answered, have you considered an alternative?  Our project [InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) allows you to install in unattended mode directly, without having to autoextract the contents. Just invoke the executable with --mode unattended, pass any additional options you may need from the command line or an external file and you are good to go. We have a lot of ex-InstallAnywhere customers :)